# Add "Tag Description" to the Tag Query on StackExchange API

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, api

Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to get a list of tag descriptions from the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#page=1&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&filter=default&site=workplace&run=true). As the above link will show you, this is the info you get out for each tag:

```
     {
       "name": "whistle-blowing",
       "count": 2,
       "is_required": false,
       "is_moderator_only": false,
       "has_synonyms": false
     },
```

I would like to have the tag description added to the data that returns from the query so that users can:

- Get a list of all tags without descriptions
- Get a consolidated list of all tags with descriptions

Ideally, the output would look like this:

```
     {
       "name": "interviewing",
       "count": 281,
       "is_required": false,
       "is_moderator_only": false,
       "has_synonyms": false,
       "excerpt": "For questions about interviews and the interviewing process.",
       "description": "`Interviewing` is the process by which a potential candidate filtered from a pool of candidates is exposed to the concerned authority for a face-to-face, telephonic or any other means of direct or indirect interview, where the `Interviewer` asks certain question to check the skills and ability of the `Interviewee`. Performance in an interview is one of the measure parameter for selecting or rejecting a candidate for a job."
     },
```

---

It looks like this information *is* currently available, but limited to [tag wiki](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags) queries, which means you need to specify up to 20 different tags. While I suppose you could chain two together, for manual searches it would be much more useful to have this attached to tag queries. I suppose this is probably a significant change due to the fact that these seem to be separate tables, but would still like to know why this is the way it is.